# while loop python cannot be fixed

Tags: python, while-loop

```
def hits():
    while True:
        hits = int(input("Number of hits :\t"))
        if hits>1000:
            print("Invalid integer. Must be from 0 to 1000.")
            print()
        **elif hit(hits)>at_bats:**    #does not know how to fix that
            print("Hits cannot be greater than at bats.")
            print()
        else :
            return hits
```

Comment: What is your program supposed to do? What problem do you encounter? What is the purpose of the while loop?

Comment: DO NOT USE THE SAME NAME WITH YOUR VARIABLE

Answer (score 1):

To make the code run, we must fix the fact that the marked line has 2 unbound names.

```
def hits():
    while True:
        hits = int(input("Number of hits :\t"))
        if not 0 <= hits <= 1000:
            print("Invalid integer. Must be from 0 to 1000.")
            print()
            continue
        at_bats = int(input("Number of at_bats :\t"))
        if hits > at_bats:
            print("Invalid integer. At_bats must be greater than hitts.")
            print()
        else :
            return hits
```

Comment: Can you please explain your `hits()` and `hits` variable?

Comment: What is there to explain?  hits() is the defined function set by def; hits is the local variable set by input.  Reusing the same name is not a great idea, but it is legal, so I did not bother to change.  The reuse means that the function cannot recursively call itself, but then this function should not do so.

Comment: If you answer have add this comment will more better :)

Answer (score -1):

I guess below maybe is what you need, though I have no idea what at_bats is.

```
   def func_hits():
        while True:
            hits = int(input("Number of hits :\t"))
            if hits>1000:
                print("Invalid integer. Must be from 0 to 1000.")
                continue
            elif hit(hits)>at_bats:    #Have no idea where that defined
                print("Hits cannot be greater than at bats.")
                continue
            else :
                return hits
```

Comment: where is your `hit` define?

Comment: This will not run.

Comment: The hig() and at_bats can not be seen. Maybe defined outside. The while loop logic seems have problem.